# APACHE BEAM GROUP DATA BY KEY

Tags: apache-beam

I have a 
`PCollection<KV<KV<String, String>, Long>`
Each item of the `PCollection` looks like that:  `KV{KV{date,name},long}`
I would like to group all item with the same date but I don't know how to do that

If someone has an idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Once you got your PCollection in KV<> format. You can use GroupBYKey PTransform in apache beam which will put all your data in Iterable with same key.

Use the below code:

```
PCollection<KV<> outputElement = inputElemeny.apply(GroupByKey.<KV<>>create());
```

Then apply Pardo on output element to get the suitable result you want.